# Can I use Stylus and/or Jade with Spring 4 MVC project?

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, pug, stylus, spring-4

I have gotten used to/fell in love with Stylus for preprocessing css and Jade for simplifying my HTML in the Node.JS world. Now I am back to working on a Spring 4 MVC project and would like to use those technologies in this environment.

Is it possible to integrate them (I am using Gradle)? A quick google search for Stylus Java Gradle returned no helpful responses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Stylus and Jade seem to be popular in the JavaScript world, not so much in the JVM world.

Here are the closest tools I know about, with good support in the JVM world:

- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), for a CSS preprocessor replacement
- [Groovy Templates](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.3/html/documentation/markup-template-engine.html) are quite close to Jade
- Spring Framework 4.1 will also include some improvements for handling static resources (see [SPR-10933](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10933) and [SPR-11800](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11800))

Comment: I +1'ed for the info, but would add that Thymeleaf is actually a pretty good templating engine as well, and seems to be the direction Spring is going towards by default (not that they force you to use it, but it's the one that they seem to favor). Also, there is SASS for CSS preprocessor which is similar to LESS.

Comment: Well, the OP was asking about similar tools (Jade, Stylus). Thymeleaf is nice, but radically different when compared to Jade and Groovy Templates (DRY, abstracts HTML markup). I agree, SASS is also widely available - actually both SASS and LESS are available with Twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I just like stylus better than LESS but maybe it is just in my head. At least Less can be processed on the client side. Outside of ruby SASS seems to have its issues (libsass). But I don't know I will look at Groovy Templates and see how similar it is. Also, there is http://grails.org/plugin/grails-jade but I am not a grails fan.

Answer (score 0):

For Jade, you can use Jade4J (https://github.com/neuland/jade4j). There is a Spring-ready version too.

Answer (score 0):

The approach we took was to use Webpack to transpile everything (Pug, Stylus, Less, Coffee, etc) then using the `generate-source` goal in Maven (might be slightly different for Gradle) we include an exec for webpack.