# Thymeleaf: pass string parameter to mixins function

Tags: pug, thymeleaf, mixins

I have function that I wrote in mixins-jade called *picture(param)* with one string parameter. It handle pictures links. Now I want to pass argument from thymeleaf. I tried many solutions also with escape sequences but none is correct. For example:

```
+picture(&#39;\' + ${myValue} + \'&#39;)
```

or

```
+picture(th:text="${value}")
```

Comment: Why are you using one template engine to write a mixin for another template engine?

Comment: Also take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511846/can-i-use-stylus-and-or-jade-with-spring-4-mvc-project